# Fancybox thingie

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flash, fancybox

I just tried to display a flash file and an image with Fancybox.

To imagine about what am I talking, please take a look on the next snapshoot:

http://screencast.com/t/eUFh94lFz

Tasks:

- fancybox to be loaded automatically on pageload with the .swf file and the .jpg
- .swf file to be centered as it is also on the example above
- .jpg file to be positioned on the right bottom of the screen/page

Partially i succeeded.

I created a hidden link:

```
<a href="media/test_video.swf" id="flash-video" style="display:none"></a>
```

Then i called it through Jquery command:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flash-video").fancybox(
    {
        'padding'               : 0,
        'autoScale'             : false,
        'padding'               : 0, 
        'margin'                : 0, 
        'easingIn'              : 'swing',
        'easingOut'             : 'swing',
        'transitionIn'          : 'fade',
        'transitionOut'         : 'fade',
        'hideOnContentClick'    : true,
        'speedIn'               : 600,
        'speedOut'              : 200,
        'overlayShow'           : true
    }
    ).trigger('click');
});
```

I created also a hidden link for the image, but it is not displayed on the Fancybox overlay.

```
<a href="media/bottom-r-img.jpg" id="flash-video" style="position:absolute;right:5px;bottom:5px;"></a>
```

Can this be done, to show up 2 media files on a fancybox overlay at the same time?

Any positive answer is well apreciated :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't have duplicated IDs in your HTML code.
Second, fancybox can only display one thing at a time.

I would suggest to hide your flash + image inline and to use the inline loader, or to load the content from a different URL using the iframe loader.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's just a testing code. I tried it also with different id's and also classes, but it seems that only at galleries can be called multiple selectors with Jquery?

Comment: Well, thank you @Capsule. I tried the inline method and now the two media files appears. The only one problem is that the image is appearing inside the flash box. I added absolute positioning to the image and relative positioning to the pagewrapper ID. Bot of files appears, I think I'm on the good way now.

Comment: `<style>
 #wrap {position: relative;}
 #wrap .bottom-r-img {position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;}
</style>`